# Pyglet Opengl VBOs

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I'm new in pyglet, B4, I've tried to use PyOpenGL with Pygame, but PyOpenGL creates weird NuffFunctionErrors, so I've moved to Pyglet.

I've tried out this code, it runs perfectly:

```python
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window()

vertices = [
    0, 0,
    window.width, 0,
    window.width, window.height]
vertices_gl = (GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_gl)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(vertices) // 2)

pyglet.app.run()
```

I've tried to rewrite this to use VBOs, but I've got a black window.
What's wrong with my code?

```python
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window()

vertices = [
    0, 0,
    window.width, 0,
    window.width, window.height]
vertices_gl = (GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)


glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

buffer=(GLuint)(0)
glGenBuffers(1,buffer)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, buffer)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 4*3,
                    vertices_gl, GL_STATIC_DRAW)


glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(vertices) // 2)

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1)
    glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Not familiar with these Java bindings, but 12 bytes (second argument to `glBufferData`) doesn't look like it would be enough for the 6 floats you have in `vertices`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi
Thanks, it has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I received the answer in comment, but the problem was that 12 bytes wan't enough 4 six floats.

Each float uses 4 byte.